# AVPlayer loading gif until first frame of video is loaded

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

Im using AVPlayer to play a video. I have to load a gif until the first frame of the video is loaded. Im using `SwiftyGif` for the same.

I have already read many of stack posts. I have tried with the different methods with video player like `.readyToPlay`, `.unknown`, but not able to access the first frame loading. Sometimes it runs well but at other times the loading doesn't come or stays there even when the video is playing

```
func showLoadingGif() {
        let gifManager = SwiftyGifManager(memoryLimit:50)
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            let gif = UIImage(gifName: "loading.gif")
            imgViewSplash = UIImageView(gifImage: gif, manager: gifManager)
        }
        else
        {
            let gif = UIImage(gifName: "loading_mobile.gif")
            imgViewSplash = UIImageView(gifImage: gif, manager: gifManager)
        }
        imgViewSplash.loopCount = 10000
        // imageview.delegate = self
        imgViewSplash.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height+100)
        imgViewSplash.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width  / 2, y: view.frame.size.height / 2)
        if self.view.subviews.contains(imgViewSplash) {
            self.imgViewSplash.removeFromSuperview() // Remove it
        }
        self.view.addSubview(imgViewSplash)

    }

    func hideLoadingGif() {
        if self.view.subviews.contains(imgViewSplash) {
            self.imgViewSplash.removeFromSuperview() // Remove it
        }
    }



self.observer = playerVideo.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (CMTime) -> Void in
            if self.playerVideo.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
                self.updateSlider(elapsedTime: CMTime)

                if let currentItem = self.playerVideo.currentItem {
                    let duration = currentItem.asset.duration
                    print("Total Duration - \(duration)")
                    self.hideLoadingGif()
                }

                let time : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.playerVideo.currentTime());
                //print("\(time)")
                print("App Into Overlay - \(time)")

                let playbackLikelyToKeepUp = self.playerVideo.currentItem?.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp
                if playbackLikelyToKeepUp == false {
                    //print("Here start the activity indicator inorder to show buffering")
                }else{
                    //print("stop the activity indicator")
                }
            }
            if self.playerVideo.currentItem?.status == .unknown
            {
                self.btnPlay.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                self.progressMainView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                self.hideLoadingGif()
            }
        }
```

The expected results should be the gif should come while video is loading and when the first frame os loaded, it should hide and video should play, but actually the gif comes and sometimes it hides before fist frame is loaded and other times it stays there and video starts playing.